# CSS on hover problems

Tags: css, hover

I have a line of text inclosed in div tags. What I would like to happen is when the mouse hovers over the text, it to be changed to the color red. Everything is working but, the problem I am facing is the hover only works when the pointer is directly on the letters. Inbetween the hover does not work even though is it applied on the parent.

```
<div class="raw">
  <div>The line of text is going to be red when hovered</div>
</div>

<div class="base highlight" style="width:auto">
  The line of text is going to be red when hovered
</div>

<style>
.base {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.highlight{
  clip-path: inset(0px 100% 0px 0px);
  color: red;
    margin-top:-18px;
    position: absolute;
}

.raw:hover~.highlight {
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
}

</style>
```

Comment: would you explain what does this mean `Inbetween the hover does not work even though is it applied on the parent.` also I made few changes and looks like it is working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/5snrbLqy/2/

Comment: Works, although when I place the red text over the other it doesn't work, I have updated my question to reflect this.